# Transitive actions of finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,\Bbb Z)$ on projective geometries

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, projective-geometry, linear-groups

For any $n$, the group ${\rm GL}(n,\Bbb Z)$ has a natural action on $\Bbb Z^n$. Modding out a prime $p$ yields an action on the vector space $F_p^n$, where $F_p$ is the finite field with $p$ elements. Projectivising gives an action on the finite projective geometry $PG_{n-1}(p)$. Therefore, every subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\Bbb Z)$ has a natural action on $PG_{n-1}(p)$, for every prime $p$.

> **Question**: Do there exist arbitrarily large primes $p$ such that, for some $n>1$, there is a finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\Bbb Z)$ whose natural action on the points of $PG_{n-1}(p)$ is transitive?

Motivation: in https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06114, Corollary 6.6, I defined a function $k_n$; in my proof of its existence, this function grows with $n$. The referee has asked the reasonable question of whether or not the actual function is unbounded. I believe this is equivalent to the question I'm asking here, but I don't know the answer.

Comment: Since scalar multiplication by any $a\in (\mathbb Z/(p\mathbb Z))^*$ is invertible, your question is the same as asking whether $GL(n,\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ acts transitively on $F_p^n\setminus\{0\}$, right?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas No, because GL(n, Z/pZ) is not a subgroup of GL(n,Z).

Comment: Oh yes - I see that now.

Comment: @Joy Morris: Just to clarify, are you asking if there are finite subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ which act transitively on $\mathbb{F}_p^n\setminus \{0\}$ (modulo scalars)?

Comment: @Venkataramana: Yes, that is the question.

Comment: In view of the number-theoretic restrictions that Geoff Robinson has shown result from transitive actions of this type, it might be worth adding number theory to the tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably final revision: I am indebted to Dave Witte-Morris, who added a reference to a refinement of Zsigmondy's Theorem by W. Feit, of which I was unaware, and pointed out that consequently, a complete answer to the question implicitly followed from what was previously written.

In fact, going beyond Dave Witte-Morris's original suggestion (but still making use of Feit's result in its more precise statement as his Theorem A), we may obtain the   sharper conclusion that if there is a transitive action of the form requested by the OP, then $p \leq 3$, so I now incorporate this observation.

The order of a finite subgroup $X$ of ${\rm PGL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is always a divisor of $\frac{(2n)!}{2}$( by the result of Blichfeldt or Minkowski mentioned below, applied to the preimage $G$ of $X$ in ${\rm GL})$. In particular, the order of a finite subgroup of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ divides $12.$ However, we note that ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has no quaternion subgroup of order $8,$ from which it easily follows that a finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has a normal $2$-complement (necessarily of order dividing $3$), and also that ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has no subgroup of order $12.$

Now ${\rm GL}(6,\mathbb{Z})$ contains no element of order $31,$ so we need not concern ourselves with the case $p =5, n = 6.$

A finite group $H$ which acts transitively on a set of $\frac{p^{n}-1}{p-1}$ points with $n >1$ has order at least $p+1$ (and if $n =2$, then such a group has order divisible by $p+1$). Hence if there is a prime $p$ as asked for in the question, we certainly have $2p < (2n)!$. If $n = 2,$ we can exclude $p = 7,$ since $p+1 =8$ does not divide the order of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z}).$ If $X$ is a finite subgroup of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ of order $6,$ then $X$ is the image of a subgroup $G \cong ( \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}) \times S_{3}$ in which every non-central involution has the eigenvalue $1$. Thus $X$ does not act regularly on ${\rm PG}_{1}(5),$ and hence does not act transitively as $|X| = 6 =|{\rm PG}_{1}(5)|.$

We can also exclude the possibility $p =11$ when $n =2,$ since no subgroup of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has order $12.$

Hence we may ( and do, from now) assume that $n >2$ and $p \geq 5.$ Furthermore, if $ p = 5,$ we may suppose that $n \neq 6,$ so we do.

A strengthening of Zsigmondy's theorem [proved by Feit](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1988-0915710-1) as his Theorem A shows  (as $p \geq  5$ and $n >2,$ with $n \neq 6$ if $p=5$), that there is a "large" Zsigmondy prime divisor $q$  of $\frac{p^{n}-1}{p-1}$, which means we can assume either that $q > n + 1$ or else that $p^n - 1$ is divisible by $q^2$. Then $q$ divides $\frac{p^{n}-1}{p-1}$ and $p$ has multiplicative order $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z},$ so that $q \equiv 1$ (mod $n$).

However, by Cauchy's theorem, $G$ contains an element, say  $x,$ of order $q.$ But $\langle x \rangle$ has no non-trivial irreducible representation of degree less than $q-1$ over $\mathbb{Q},$ so we must have $n = q-1$ (this also implicitly shows that $G$ contains no element of order $q^{2}).$ Thus $x$ has trace $-1$ in the given representation, and a Lemma of Blichfeldt (or maybe Minkowski, as J-P. Serre attributes it) shows that $\langle x \rangle$ must be a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G,$ so that, in particular, $\frac{p^{n}-1}{p-1}$ is not divisible by $q^{2}.$ Since $q$ is a Zsigmondy prime, we know that $p - 1$ is not divisible by $q$, so this implies that $p^{n}-1$ is not divisible by $q^{2}.$ This contradicts the fact that $q$ is a "large" Zsigmondy prime.

( For the sake of completeness, I outline the argument of Blichfeldt used, or an alternative using basic character theory: Let $Q$ be a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G,$ and let $\chi$ denote the character of $G$ afforded by the given representation. Then $Q$ has exponent $q,$ and we have see that $\chi(x) = -1$ for each non-identity element of $Q$. Now the (necessarily integral) multiplicity of the trivial character in ${\rm Res}^{G}_{Q}(\chi)$ is given by 
$\frac{1}{|Q|} ( (q-1) - (|Q|-1)).$ Hence $|Q|$ divides $|Q|-q$ which forces $|Q| = q.$ The result of Blichfeldt alluded to is the observation that if $\mu$ is a faithful complex character of a finite group $X$ and $c_{1},c_{2}, \ldots, c_{r}$ are all the distinct values assumed by $\mu$ on non-identity elements of $X$ then $|X|$ divides $\prod_{i=1}^{r}( \mu(1) - c_{i})).$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem

Comment: We can thus wonder in general, for prime $q$, what is the maximal order of a finite subgroup of $GL_{q-1}(\mathbf{Z})$ of order divisible by $q$. (This in particular discards subgroups of maximal order, namely $2^{q-1}(q-1)!$ if $q\ge 13$, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168292/)

Comment: @YCor: Yes, I was trying to crystallize what I know about this question,, and was trying to marshal my thoughts to write more later as I indicated. Brauer and Feit ( following Blichfeldt) and Feit-Thompson ( and some of their students) did much work on finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ of order divisible by a prime $q > n.$

Comment: @YCor: Yes the requirement is that the Sylow $q$-subgroup is not Abelian normal.

Comment: It seems to me that once you have $n+1 = q$ is prime (and not two) you can run virtually the same argument on a Zsygmondy prime dividing $p^m-1$ where $m = n/2$ to get that $m+1$ is also prime.

Comment: @YCor: I deleted some of the exchange: to return to your original question, I see no reason why the $\mathbb{Z}$-form for the "natural" irreducible  module for $A_{q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should be unique up to integral equivalence..

Comment: Thinking twice, we can get a twisted form by considering the action of $\mathrm{Alt}_q$ on the subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}^q$ of those $(n_1,\dots,n_q)$ with $\sum n_i=0$ and $q| n_i-n_j$ for all $i$; this is an action on a certain free abelian group of rank $q$. It is not integrally conjugate to the standard action, because the action preserves an additive subgroup of index $q$ (namely those $q$-tuples of $q\mathbf{Z}$ with sum 0). Anyway I doubt it's relevant to the original question (my mistake! but I like digressions).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I edited your answer, because the first half of your argument provides a complete proof if you replace Zsigmondy's theorem with an improved version due to Feit. Well done!

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Is there a reference for the fact that if the representation of $G$ is not absolutely irreducible, then either $\langle x \rangle \lhd G$, or else $G/Z(G) \cong {\rm PSL}(2,q)$? (At least, the case $q = 7$?) Joy and I think that your argument plus results on maximal finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for $n = 4, 6, 12$ by [Dade](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067584), [Plesken-Pohst](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2006437), and [Plesken-Nebe](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/memo/0556) shows that if a finite subgroup is transitive (and $n > 1$) then $q = n = 2$.

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris: If our $G \leq {\rm GL}(q-1,\mathbb{Z})$ with Sylow $q$-subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ of order $q$ is not absolutely irreducible, and $\langle x \rangle \not \lhd G,$ then $G$ has a complex irreducible character $\chi$ of degree at most $\frac{q-1}{2}$ whose kernel does not contain $x$. Hence $K = {\rm ker}(\chi)$ is a $q^{\prime}$-group,, and it follows that the character of the given rational representation of $G$ is the sum of the Galois conjugates of $\chi,$ so that $\chi$ is in fact faithful.

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris : Hence $G$ has a faithful irreducible complex character $\chi$ of degree at most $\frac{q-1}{2}.$ The finite irreducible subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and ${\rm GL}(3,\mathbb{C})$ have been known since before 1900 ( references probably Jordan, Blichfeldt) , so $q = 5$ or $q=7$ is no problem anyway. Only $A_{5}$ ( in degree $2$) and $A_{5},A_{6}$ or ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ in degree $3$,, arise as possibilities for $G/Z(G)$ if $G$ does not have an Abelian normal subgroup of index dividing $6.$

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris: For $q>7,$ the result follows by a Theorem of Feit and Thompson, Pacific J Math 11, (1961) if $\chi(1) < \frac{q-1}{2}$ although I think that Brauer ( and maybe Tuan) had already done the case when  $q$ divides to the first power only. If $\chi(1) = \frac{q-1}{2},$ it is a Theorem of Brauer ( and maybe Tuan) from the 1940s  when $q$ divides to the first power that $G/Z(G)$ must be ${\rm PSL}(2,q),$ which does occur.

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris: The 1961 paper of Feit and Thompson should have the right Brauer references. By the way, if $\chi$ is imprimitive ( that, is, is induced from a proper subgroup $H$), then it is easy to see that $\langle x \rangle \lhd G,$ so we only need worry about primitive ( ie not induced from proper subgroups) characters.

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris : I'm slightly confused about whether you mean $p$ or $q.$ In what I wrote, $q$ is the Zsigmondy prime divisor of $\frac{p^{n}-1}{2}.$ I did think I had an argument to deal with $p =3,$ but I realised I had not dealt with one of the exceptions in Feit's paper, which you have maybe now dealt with.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks, Geoff!  I'm sorry for mixing up p and q in my last comment. (I will return to the original notation.) We are still writing it down, but eliminating $p = 3$ (and eliminating $p = 2$ when $n > 2$) does not seem to be difficult, given the strong results on maximal finite subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. When $p = 3$, we have $n \in \{4,6\}$ (or $n = 2$, which is easy).

Comment: Of [Dade's](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067584) 9 maximal finite subgroups of $GL(4,\mathbb{Z})$, only three have order divisible by 5. For each of those, Dade gives an invariant set $S$ of 10 or 20 vectors. So the group cannot be transitive on a set of $(3^{4} - 1)/(3 - 1) = 40$ points. To rule out $n = 6$, note that  $(3^6 - 1)/(3 - 1) = (3^3 + 1)(3^3 - 1)/2$ is divisible by 13. This can't occur because $13 > n + 1$. This finishes the proof for $p = 3$. It's not quite so easy to rule out $p = 2$. (The list of maximal subgroups for $n = 6$ is only the absolutely irreducible ones.)

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris: OK, good luck finishing that. I agree that $p =3, n =4$ or $6$ is not difficult, although I had not checked it myself. I  hadn't thought about $p = 2, n > 2.$