# Finite linear groups with integer entries

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a classification of maximal finite subgroups of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$
for fixed $n$?
For $n$ sufficiently large the signed symmetric group is the subgroup of maximal order,
but is anything known about other maximal subgroups?

Comment: Weyl groups provide a list of examples, of which I think many are maximal.

Comment: I think this has been asked before ( and maybe I even answered it).  I think for maximal (absolutely) irreducible groups the answer is known, and for small $n$, lists were given by Feit. For reducible groups, the answer might get messy. Knowing which are maximal under inclusion ( not just of maximal order) seems difficult in  either case for moderately large $n$.

Comment: Look at work of Gaby Nebe. Plesken did also some work on such questions.

Comment: This is tightly related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168292/ which asks the weaker question about what the maximal orders of subgroups are. The sad situation is that there is a claimed result there which lots of people use and referenced, but no published proof (to the best of my knowledge). So I am not sure if there really is a complete rigorous answer to your question out there (if there is, I wish to learn about it, too!)

Comment: As I said in my old answer, there was definitely a preprint by Feit. Since he died not long after, it may have never been published. The work of Weisfeiler was updated and completed by M.J. Collins for general finite complex linear groups, and that has been published. I know that Collins has written up versions for $\mathbb{Q}$ and some cyclotomic cases, but I do not know their publication status.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Geoff! I never doubted that the preprint by Feit exists. Regarding M. J. Collins, that's a great hint, I already found three papers by him that seem relevant and will dig a bit further. Thanks again!