Large(ish) finite non-abelian subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_n \mathbb C$ for $n>70$
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$My question is about large order finite non-abelian subgroups of $\GL_n\C$ without an abelian normal subgroup (or "small" abelian normal subgroup). I could look at $\SU_n$ as well since all finite subgroups of $\GL_n\C$ can be conjugated to an $\SU_n$ subgroup. For low $n$ it seems there isn't a regular pattern, for $\SU_2$ we have the binary icosahedral group, for $\SU_3$ there is the Valentiner group, for $\SU_4$ we have the result from Hanany and He (arXiv link) which gives a full classification. But Jordan's and Collins' well-known results say there might be something happening at $n=70$. I also understand that a full classification of all finite subgroups is hopeless for general $n$.
So let's limit ourselves to $n>70$, maybe we can find a pattern for these. Is it possible to give a finite non-abelian subgroup, without an (or "small") abelian normal subgroup, parametrized by $n$, such that for any $n$ it's a “large” subgroup? What I mean is that it doesn't have to have the largest order (if finding the largest order finite non-abelian subgroup is impossible), but reasonably large number of elements, for example exponential in $n$. Or if having no abelian normal subgroup is difficult, let's have as small an abelian normal subgroup as possible.
I know this is rather vague. But the reason I'm hoping something like this is possible is that groups $\PSL_kq$ do show up for various $n$ and maybe, perhaps for only even or only odd $n$, one can have explicitly $k$ and $q$ as a function of $n$ such that the order of $\PSL_kq$ is “large” and is a subgroup of $\GL_n\C$.
In other words, are there specific embeddings of $\PSL_kq$ into $\GL_n\C$ which work for all sufficiently large $n$?
For example the group of signed permutation matrices on $n$ elements has order $2^n n!$, so I'd think it should be possible to find other, possibly larger subgroups, with exponential order in $n$.
Is there a subgroup, for sufficiently large $n$, the order of which is exponential in $n$ and larger than $2^n n!$ ?
I went through the following, which partly inspired the question:
[1] The finite subgroups of SU(n)
[2] Finite simple groups and $ \operatorname{SU}_n $
[3] Closed Lie subgroups of $\mathrm{SU}(3)$
[4] Finite maximal closed subgroups of Lie groups

$\mathrm{SU}(2)$ contains arbitrarily large dihedral groups.

What do you mean here? I thought there is a maximal order for a non-abelian finite subgroup of any SU$_n$.

Clearly not: that is the point of my previous comment. On the other hand if you restrict to rational entries the situation changes. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15127/the-maximum-order-of-finite-subgroups-in-gln-q

So then what's the definition for the subgroup of SU$_2$ which has the answer: the icosahedral group. I thought that's maximal in some sense.

You can only bound ( in terms of $n$) the index of a maximal Abelian normal subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ in general (this is basically Jordan's theorem). If you want to bound the order of a finite subgroup of ${\rm SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ you have to look at (irreducible and) primitive subgroups, in which case it can be done ( again, a bound in terms of $n$).

For ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, any finite primitive subgroup $G$ does have $[G:Z(G)] \leq 60.$

@SeanEberhard on the rational case: your link points to a discussion of finite subgroups of maximal order in GL(n,Q), which is quite hard. But proving that there is a bound on orders of finite subgroups is very elementary. First they are conjugate into GL(n,Z) (easy, finding an invariant lattice) and then the bound follows using a torsion-free finite index subgroup, e.g. the 3rd congruence subgroup. This gives a bound $<3^{n^2}$ on the orders of finite subgroups of GL(n,Q), which of course is not optimal.

For finite subgroups of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Q}),$ there is a finite subgroup of order $2^{n}n!$, while by an argument of H. Blichfeldt, any finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{Q})$ has order dividing $(2n)!$.

What are the "well-known" results for $n=70$ that you mention?

If $n$ is even, $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ contains a copy of $S_{n+1}$ as well as a copy of $\mathrm{SL}2(5)^{n/2} \rtimes S{n/2}$ (since $\mathrm{SL}_2(5)$ embeds in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$). The former group has no abelian normal subgroup at all, while the latter group has a normal abelian subgroup of index $60^{n/2} (n/2)!$. I believe the point about $n = 70$ is just that $(n+1)! > 60^{n/2} (n/2)!$ for $n > 70$ but not for $n \le 70$.

Anyway the Collins paper is here: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/JGT.2007.032/html?lang=en

@Fetchinson0234 There's a reasonable queue which returns icosahedral group on SU(2): the largest finite subgroup without normal abelian subgroups.

@DenisT Thanks, I'll add this to the original post.

@GeoffRobinson I think I've seen an answer from you, which was helpful (although without an explicit construction), but now it's gone, do you plan to post it again or at least put it into a comment?

OK, I deleted it, but now I have undeleted it.

I think one detail in some parts of the above discussion is slightly wrong. The “icosahedral group” (ie $A_5$) is not a subgroup of $SU(2)$; it’s a subgroup of $SO(3)\cong SU(2)/{\pm I}$. Its preimage in $SU(2)$ is the binary icosahedral group, which has order 120 and has a non-trivial abelian normal subgroup.

@HJRW That's true, updated the original post.

Your question is indeed somewhat vaguely formulated, but here is an attempt to state some known and fairly up to date facts. If $G$ is a finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $n > 151$, then $G$ has an Abelian normal subgroup $A$ with $[G:A] \leq 60^{n-1}$ UNLESS $G$ has a composition factor $A_{m}$ (alternating group)  with $m > 151.$
On the other hand, for large $n$, it is possible to find finite nilpotent subgroups $G$ of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ with $|G| > c^{n-1}$ for some constant $c > 1$. Also, for any finite nilpotent subgroup $H$ of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C}),$ there is an Abelian normal subgroup $A$ of $H$ with $[H:A] \leq 2^{n-1}.$
For a finite simple group $G$ of Lie type, it is a (slight extension of a ) Theorem of E. Artin that $G$ has a nilpotent subgroup $U$ with $|G| < |U|^{3}.$
From these facts, it is possible to deduce (among other things) that there is a single fixed constant $h$ such that if $G$ is a finite simple group of Lie type which is a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ for some $n$, then $|G| \leq h^{n-1}$. Since there are only finitely many sporadic simple groups, we can enlarge the constant $h$ to cover sporadic simple groups.
This is basically the reason why we need large Alternating composition factors for $G$ if we are to be unable to bound $[G:A]$ (for $G$ a finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $A$ an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$ of maximal order) by a bound of the form $[G:A] < d^{n}$ for a chosen constant $d$.

This is very useful, although not constructive examples of specific subgroups. The intent here was to find specific subgroups for any $n$, I'm guessing in the form PSL$_kq$, but other forms are also fine, as long as they are ``large'' in some vague sense, for example the order is exponential in $n$.

There are bounds of Landazuri and Seitz, and also refinements by Tiep which give fairly close to optimal bounds for complex  linear representations of quasisimple groups.

For example, ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ has a complex representation of degree $\frac{q^{n}-1}{q-1} -1$ and that degree is usually not far from minimal (subject to being faithful).

And what is the dimension of the representation? Or more precisely, what is the embedding into GL$_n$C?

Take the permutation action of ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ on one -dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field of $q$ elements. Think of that as a representation via (complex( permutation matrices. Then note that there is a one-dimensional fixed space (spanned by the all ones vector), and use Maschke's theorem to get a complex linear representation of degree $\frac{q^{n}-1}{q-1} -1.$

That's very useful again, in order to avoid confusion about the notation let's have PSL$_kq$ and aim for GL$_nC$, then from what you say $k=2$ and $q=n$ is always a solution but of course this only works with $n$ being a power of a prime. And the order of PSL$_2n$ will only be polynomial in $n$. Shouldn't there be a construction where the order of the group is exponential in $n$?

@Fetchinson0234 Why?

Why I'm expecting a subgroup with an order that's exponential in $n$? I don't know, that's just a guess, I'm not sure how large the order can be given $n$, that's part of the question. But the second paragraph of @GeoffRobinson's answer hints that it can be exponential.

Apart from alternating composition factors, to get an exponential ( in $n$) size finite subgroup of ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ (modulo an Abelian normal subgroup) you need to look at wreath product constructions.

I just realized, and updated the original post, that signed permutations on $n$ elements is obviously a subgroup, and has order $n! 2^n$ which is exponential. I'm wondering if by wreath product constructions one can increase this order.

That example is mentioned (implicitly) in my comments on your post ( some of which are hidden by the system). But that example has a large alternating composition factor ( ie $A_{n}$). Also, the order in that example exceeds $c^{n}$ for large enough $n$ for any fixed choice of constant $c$, so it's really a super-exponential bound.

I see, indeed you mentioned it, and clearly $n!2^n$ grows faster than exponential, so how is this example compatible with the 4th paragraph of your answer above? I'm probably missing something obvious.

For the first question above, it gets bigger than exponential because of the large alternating composition factor, as I indicated on my answer and in other comments.

For the second question, ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ certainly does not have a non- trivial complex representation of degree $n$ if the prime $p$ which divides $q$ is greater than $2n+1$, for example (by a theorem of Feit and Thompson).

I often get advised here on MO that if an original question branches out into a separate question I should open a new post instead, so I'll do that, about the representations of $PSL(n,q)$.
